# ADJUST/EDIT SQL QUERY ASSISTANCE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the below query which calculates from the first requested date to first completed date how much time elapsed. 
However in the example below there is a requested date of 2017-02-02 (backdated) which was created on the 2017-02-06.

I want to edit the query to select the requested date and calculate how much time elapsed until completed from the **FIRST** **CREATED DATE**

So right now it returns 1 when it should be 0 
Reasoning, because first created date is 2017-02-03 and it was requested and completed on the same day 2017-02-03

Any help is appreciated greatly!

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(Identifier     VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
 Created_Date   DATETIME NOT NULL,
 Requested_Date DATETIME NOT NULL,
 Completed_Date DATETIME NULL,
 SN_Type        VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 SN_Status      VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES
('11111',
 '20170203',
 '20170203',
 '20170203',
 'Re-Activattion',
 'COMP'
);
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES
('11111',
 '20170206',
 '20170202',
 NULL,
 'Re-Activattion',
 'N-CO'
);
SELECT *
FROM #temp;

-- calculate/identify Order start and Order End records
WITH cte
     AS (
    -- 1st Order start record i.e. earliest record in the table for a given "Identifier"

     SELECT Identifier,
            MIN(Created_Date) AS Created_Date,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), 'Created') AS RecordType,
            1 AS OrderNumber
     FROM #temp
     GROUP BY Identifier
     UNION ALL
    -- All records with "COMP" status are treated as order completed events. Add 2 weeks to the completed date to create a "dummy" Order End Date

     SELECT Identifier,
            DATEADD(WEEK, 2, Created_Date) AS Created_Date,
            'Completed' AS RecordType,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Identifier ORDER BY Created_Date) AS OrderNumber
     FROM #temp
     WHERE SN_STATUS = 'COMP'
     UNION ALL
    -- Set the start period of the next order to be right after (3 ms) the previous Order End Date

     SELECT Identifier,
            DATEADD(ms, 3, DATEADD(WEEK, 2, Created_Date)) AS Created_Date,
            'Created' AS RecordType,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Identifier ORDER BY Created_Date) + 1 AS OrderNumber
     FROM #temp
     WHERE SN_STATUS = 'COMP'),
-- Combine Start / End records into one record
     OrderGroups
     AS (
     SELECT Identifier,
            OrderNumber,
            MIN(Created_Date) AS OrderRangeStartDate,
            MAX(Created_Date) AS OrderRangeEndDate
     FROM cte
     GROUP BY Identifier,
              OrderNumber)
     SELECT a.Identifier,
            a.OrderNumber,
            OrderRangeStartDate,
            OrderRangeEndDate,
            CASE
                WHEN SUM(CASE
                             WHEN SN_STATUS = 'COMP'
                                  AND SN_TYPE = 'Re-Activattion'
                             THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                         END) > 0
                THEN STR(DATEDIFF(day, MIN(CASE
                                               WHEN SN_TYPE = 'Re-Activattion'
                                               THEN Requested_Date
                                               ELSE NULL
                                           END), MIN(CASE
                                                         WHEN(SN_TYPE = 'Re-Activattion'
                                                              AND SN_STATUS = 'COMP')
                                                         THEN Completed_Date
                                                         ELSE NULL
                                                     END)))
                WHEN SUM(CASE
                             WHEN SN_TYPE = 'Re-Activattion'
                             THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                         END) > 0
                THEN 'NOT COMP'
                ELSE 'NO RE-ACT'
            END AS RE_ACT_COMPLETION_TIME,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN SN_STATUS = 'N-CO'
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END) AS [RE-AN NCO #]
     FROM OrderGroups AS a
          INNER JOIN #Temp AS b ON a.Identifier = b.Identifier
                                   AND a.OrderRangeStartDate <= b.Created_Date
                                   AND b.Created_Date <= a.OrderRangeEndDate
     GROUP BY a.Identifier,
              a.OrderNumber,
              OrderRangeStartDate,
              OrderRangeEndDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to edit the query to select the requested date and calculate
>   how much time elapsed until completed from the FIRST CREATED DATE

Change this:

```
                       ,MIN(case
                               when SN_TYPE = 'Re-Activattion'
                               then Requested_Date
                               else null
                            end
```

To this:

```
                       ,MIN(case
                               when SN_TYPE = 'Re-Activattion'
                               then Created_Date
                               else null
                            end
```

Comment: But i don't want to count from the created date. i want to count from the requested date of the FIRST created date. is there a way of doing that

Comment: Yes, with a sub-query getting the top 1 RequestedDate, ORDER BY CreatedDate.

Comment: Can you demonstrate, not sure what you mean.